# HTML from dropdown lists third category

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Yesterday i asked how i could generate a second dropdown list for a subcategory, so in the first dropdown i would select "Trucks" and a second dropdown would appear with the colors "Black" or "White" to pick or if in the first dropdown i select "Cars" the second generated dropdown would have "Red", "Green" or "Blue" options, that lead to this http://jsfiddle.net/7YeL6/5/ that i implemented in my code and works like a charm (i already put more results in the ".js" and is working 100%).

But now im facing a new problem because i need to generate a third category and i dont know anything about jquery.

Based on the previous code, i need a third dropdown to appear based on the second dropdown so for example:
If i select "Trucks", then "Black" a new dropdown will appear to select "New" or "Used" or if i select "Cars", then "Red" a new dropdown will appear to select "Buy" or "Rent".

**HTML CODE**

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option selected value="Please Select">Please Select</option>           
    <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="Trucks">Trucks</option>
    <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
    <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
</select>

<div>
<select name="category2" id="truck" class="second">
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>            
</select>

<select name="category2" id="car" class="second">
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>           
</select>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
#category2{
    display: none;
}
.second{
    display: none;

}
```

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#category").change(function () {
  var str = "";
str =  $("select#category option:selected").text();
    if(str == "Trucks"){
        $("select.second").not("#truck").hide();
        $("#truck").show();
        $("#truck").fadeIn(1000);
    }
    else if(str == "Cars"){
        $("select.second").not("#car").hide();
        $("#car").show();
        $("#car").fadeIn(1000);
    }

})
});
```

Thanks

Comment: CSS selectors, such as "#category2" are applied to element IDs, not form element NAMES.

Comment: im new to this and as i said i dont understand much of jquery, but i can tell this code is working fine on the backend im working on =/. Should i change something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you wanted to this instead

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7YeL6/7/

**HTML CODE**

```
<select id="category" class="first">
    <option selected value="Please Select">Please Select</option>           
    <option value="car">Cars</option>
    <option value="truck">Trucks</option>
    <option value="motor">Motorcycles</option>
    <option value="boat">Boats</option>
</select>

<select id="truck" class="second">
        <option selected value="Please Select">Please Select</option>    
        <option value="white">white</option>
        <option value="black">black</option>            
</select>
<select id="car" class="second">
        <option selected value="Please Select">Please Select</option>    
        <option value="red">red</option>
        <option value="green">green</option>
        <option value="blue">blue</option>           
</select>

<select id="truck-white" class="third">
        <option value="size1">truck-white1</option>
        <option value="size2">truck-white2</option>            
</select>
<select id="truck-black" class="third">
        <option value="size1">truck-black1</option>
        <option value="size2">truck-black2</option>            
</select>
<select id="car-red" class="third">
        <option value="1">car-red1</option>
        <option value="2">car-red2</option>
        <option value="3">car-red3</option>           
</select>
<select id="car-green" class="third">
        <option value="1">car-green1</option>
        <option value="2">car-green2</option>
        <option value="3">car-green3</option>           
</select>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.second{
    display: none;
}
.third{
    display: none;
}
```

**JQuery CODE**

```
$(".first").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str =  $(this).val();
    $('.second').hide();
    $('.third').hide();
    $('#'+str).show();
});
$(".second").change(function () {
    var str = "";
    str =  $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.third').hide();
    $('#' + id + "-" + str).show();
})
```

Comment: wow cao. thanks. i will try it and give feedback in no time. Awesome! by the way, is possible to do that and appear a title also, above the dropdown, in new div or cell in <td>?

Comment: yes, it's can do that. But, you should do this by yourself, you will be a good jQuery programmer.

Comment: yeah, i hope so. if its possible i will try with same method then. thanks again for everything m8. looks awesome